# Harvey Dent black?

Tags: casting, the-dark-knight, continuity, comic-adaptation, batman-1989

I was watching Tim Burton's Batman series and found out that Harvey Dent was played by a black man but he is played by a white guy in Nolan's series. What race is Harvey Dent portrayed as in the comics, and why the discrepancies?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why did Tommy Lee Jones play Harvey Dent in Batman Forever?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27892/why-did-tommy-lee-jones-play-harvey-dent-in-batman-forever)

Comment: @Richard That seems to ask an entirely different question, though.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Yes, but the answer to that question answers this question. *"**Since Dent was white in the comics,** and since Billy Dee Williams' role in the first film was rather small, and since the role of Batman himself had been recast anyway, it seems Schumacher didn't feel the need to maintain this particular continuity"*.

Comment: @Richard But it's still a different question. I know that other sites might have quite a more answer-centric duplicate policy, but I can't see how those two questions even remotely ask the same question.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - per the FAQ "*There are many ways to ask the same question, and a user might not be able to find the answer if they're asking it a different way.*". I defer to your judgement on this, but my take has always been that if you can copy/paste the answer over, it's almost certainly a dupe.

Comment: @Richard Well, you can only copy the answer over in this case, since one of the users answering the other question chose to adress a marginal aspect relevant for this question in his answer. It is not that you could copy over every possible reasonable answer to the other question. The user asking this question isn't really "asking the other question in a different way", he doesn't seem to care at all why the actor changed from Billie Dee Williams to Thommy Lee Jones, neither does the asker of the other question seem to care about Harvey Dent's racial background.

Comment: It may have happened that Burton didn't consider adding two-face as a villain in any sequel, and included Harvey Dent as a really small character not caring too much whether his ethnicity was canon.

Answer (score 1):

They're both technically true, as each adaptation has its own official canon.

The canon with Billy Dee Williams as Harvey Dent continues on from the first two Tim Burton films, with Tommy Lee Jones taking over the role as Two-Face in Batman Forever. Billy Dee Williams was initially intended to portray Harvey Dent post-mutilation, but the role was given to Tommy Lee Jones. However, it is considered the same character.

As for the portrayal of Harvey Dent in The Dark Knight, the character is in a different continuity than the Tim Burton/Joel Schumacher canon.

Comment: He asked for the conformation of the race from the comics

Comment: @AnkitSharma The question was significantly changed. The first version asked for "true" which is a concept that can't be applied to fictional figures and adaptations (because everything that is done is "true" there).

Comment: @his oops my bad.

Answer (score -2):

Harvey was white in the comics:

[image: harvey dent]

Comment: while this partially answers the question, could you address as to WHY there was a difference?

Comment: I honestly do not know. Maybe he just happened to be the best fit for the character at that time? I know he was supposed to play Two-Face in Batman Forever but the director chose to cast Tommy Lee Jones instead. I've looked everywhere for the answer to this question and I have found no answer to give you. I wish I could be more help finding out the answer, but I can't.